# Can't start Kafka Connect: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-ranger

Trying to run Kafka Connect for the first time, with an existing Kafka deployment. using SASL_PLAINTEXT and kerberos authentication.

The first time I try and start `connect-distributed`, I see:

```
ERROR Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:227)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

If I immediately run a second time, not changing anything, instead I see:

```
ERROR Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:227)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [Offsets]
```

This is reproducible.

Worker config:

```
producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
bootstrap.servers=mybroker:9092
rest.port=28082
group.id=some-group
config.storage.topic=Configs
offset.storage.topic=Offsets
status.storage.topic=Status
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
log4j.root.loglevel=INFO
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
consumer.sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
consumer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
producer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
producer.sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
producer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
```

Comment: are you using `ssl` for connecting to topic?

Comment: If I've configured it correctly then it should not be trying to use SSL. I'm reusing config that worked fine with the console producer/consumer.

Comment: Can you share your worker config please

Answer (score 1):

A career in software has taught me to always assume that the problem is completely unrelated to the error log, but for once it was correct:

Ranger was configured incorrectly and I genuinely wasn't authorized to access that topic.

Comment: so what did you do, exactly? I also have `sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="admin" \
  password="secret";` for producer and consumer too but still same error